# Plotting a bar graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a snapshot of data:
[image]

```
restaurant_change_sales = c(3330.443, 3122.534)
restaurant_change_labor = c(696.592, 624.841)
restaurant_change_POS = c(155.48, 139.27)
rest_change = data.frame(restaurant_change_sales, restaurant_change_labor, restaurant_change_POS)
```

I want two bars for each of the columns indicating the change. One graph for each of the columns.

I tried:

```
ggplot(aes(x = rest_change$restaurant_change_sales), data = rest_change) + geom_bar()
```

This is not giving the result the way I want. Please help!!

Comment: I tried to copy your image of the data into R so I could test your code, but it doesn't work. Could you provide it as text instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data are not formatted properly to work well with ggplot2, or really any of the plotting packages in R.  So we'll fix your data up first, and then use ggplot2 to plot it.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# We need to differentiate between the values in the rows for them to make sense.
rest_change$category <- c('first val', 'second val')

# Now we use tidyr to reshape the data to the format that ggplot2 expects.
rc2 <- rest_change %>% gather(variable, value, -category)
rc2

# Now we can plot it.
# The category that we added goes along the x-axis, the values go along the y-axis.
# We want a bar chart and the value column contains absolute values, so no summation
# necessary, hence we use 'identity'.
# facet_grid() gives three miniplots within the image for each of the variables.
ggplot2(rc2, aes(x=category, y=value, facet=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    facet_grid(~variable)
```

Answer (score 3):

So ... something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

restaurant_change_sales = c(3330.443, 3122.534)
restaurant_change_labor = c(696.592, 624.841)
restaurant_change_POS = c(155.48, 139.27)
rest_change = data.frame(restaurant_change_sales,
                         restaurant_change_labor, 
                         restaurant_change_POS)

cbind(rest_change,
      change = c("Before", "After")) %>%
  gather(key,value,-change) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = change,
             y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~key)
```

Which will produce:

[image]

---

Edit:

To be extra fancy e.g. make it so that the order of x-axis labels goes from "Before" to "After", you can add this line: `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Before", "After"))` to the end of the ggplot function

Answer (score 0):

You have to melt your data:

```
library(reshape2) # or library(data.table)
rest_change$rowN <- 1:nrow(rest_change)
rest_change <- melt(rest_change, id.var = "rowN")
ggplot(rest_change,aes(x = rowN, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```